# String literal to basic_string<unsigned char>

Tags: c++, string, unicode, internationalization

When it comes to internationalization & Unicode, I'm an idiot American programmer.  Here's the deal.

```
#include <string>
using namespace std;

typedef basic_string<unsigned char> ustring;

int main()
{
    static const ustring my_str = "Hello, UTF-8!"; // <== error here
    return 0;
}
```

This emits a not-unexpected complaint:

`cannot convert from 'const char [14]' to 'std::basic_string<_Elem>'`

Maybe I've had the wrong portion of coffee today.  How do I fix this?  Can I keep the basic structure:

`ustring something = {insert magic incantation here};`

?

Comment: Doesn't answer your question, but read this article on i18n: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Comment: You probably need to provide your own `char_traits<unsigned char>` specialization. AFAIK, `<string>` only provides specializations for `char` and `wchar_t`.

Comment: Would there be an issue using std::string instead?  I gather you are using utf-8 so individual characters could end up negative (so to speak).  If you eliminate the const and typecast the string as unsigned char* it will allow the assignment, but it doesn't look pretty.

Comment: @Daryl:  I'm using libxml which passes around a bunch of `unsigned char*`, so I think std::string is a no-go

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Narrow string literals are defined to be `const char` and there aren't unsigned string literals[1], so you'll have to cast:

```
ustring s = reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>("Hello, UTF-8");
```

Of course you can put that long thing into an inline function:

```
inline const unsigned char *uc_str(const char *s){
  return reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>(s);
}

ustring s = uc_str("Hello, UTF-8");
```

Or you can just use `basic_string<char>` and get away with it 99.9% of the time you're dealing with UTF-8.

[1] Unless `char` is unsigned, but whether it is or not is implementation-defined, blah, blah.

Comment: @Steve, I know this is old, but I'm curious, when does `basic_string<char>` not work for storing UTF-8 encoded strings? It is just storing a sequence of bytes which has never failed me yet. Is there a corner case I'm not aware of?

Answer (score 1):

Using different character types for a different encodings has the advantages that the compiler barks at you when you mess them up. The downside is, you have to manually convert.

A few helper functions to the rescue:

```
inline ustring convert(const std::string& sys_enc) {
  return ustring( sys_enc.begin(), sys_enc.end() );
}

template< std::size_t N >
inline ustring convert(const char (&array)[N]) {
  return ustring( array, array+N );
}

inline ustring convert(const char* pstr) {
  return ustring( reinterpret_cast<const ustring::value_type*>(pstr) );
}
```

Of course, all these fail silently and fatally when the string to convert contains anything other than ASCII.

Comment: Somehow I cannot use the third overload of `convert`. I get the following compile error: `error: cast from 'const char*' to 'std::__cxx11::basic_string<unsigned char>::value_type {aka unsigned char}' loses precision [-fpermissive]
   return ustring( reinterpret_cast<ustring::value_type>(pstr) );`. [coliru link](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/66b1d6c08a1ad63e)

Comment: @Patryk: I believe I've fixed this now. Sorry I got this wrong so long ago.

Comment: That's what we have SO for :)