# Force std::string to use unsigned char (0 to 255) instead of char (-128 to 127)

Tags: c++, string

Is there a way to force string use unsigned char instead of char? Perhaps in constructor?

I need to do arithmetic operations (mostly incrementing, decrementing,  ~ (bitwise NOT)), and I need to be able to use overflow 255++ == 0... Not 127++ == -128 (and underflow 0-- == 255...)

I am not sure if question makes sense, to put some light on it here is a good question abou topic (streams) [Why do C++ streams use char instead of unsigned char?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/277655/why-do-c-streams-use-char-instead-of-unsigned-char)

I am not trying to convert string to unsigned char I found a lot of questions how to convert between the two.

Comment: Unrelated to answer: `char` is not necessarily (-128 to 127). It may behave as `signed char` or `unsigned char`

Comment: Are you actually using the string as a string?

Comment: I am using it as string In a sense; I copy (strdup()) to string variables optarg from getopt, I use something like this to get rid of white spaces while(fin >> skipws >> ch) my_string.append(&ch); ( ch is type of char) and I plan using something like my_string[i]++ to increment...

Comment: I asked in order to decide, whether I should upvote the `std::vector` or `std::basic_string` answer. `std::basic_string<unsigned char>` seems to be closer to your question, but  `my_string[i]++` indicates, you are not really treating the contents as a string but rather a collection of bytes, in which case I'd favor `std::vector<unsigned char>` but this would require you to change other parts of your code as well.

Comment: Oh I am not a c++ guru at all I would definitely have to change lots of code. Firstly I was using pure char/unsigned char (not string) then I rewrote it to use string because of lot of .methods. Now I am deciding to use ustring only in few parts of code where I need to use overflows and underflows (and ~). Thank you for your input.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use:

```
typedef std::basic_string<unsigned char> ustring;
```

And then use `ustring` instead of `std::string`

Comment: Thank you I will test this out :)

Comment: Is it possible ustring test; test = "ABCD"; ?

Comment: No you cannot do it this way because you don't have a `operator=(const char*)` for `ustring`

Comment: @Patryk I figured and I am using one of functions presented by you to convert string to ustring. Thank you. (also you made sense what string really is) +1.

Comment: @Kyslik One way to do this is [`ustring test = reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char *>("abcd");`](http://ideone.com/R6Xpjd) though I won't recommend it. Another is the converter function as you mentioned.

Answer (score 4):

`std::string` in reality is just a [`std::basic_string<char>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string)

What you need is a `std::basic_string<unsigned char>`

There are some nice conversion methods in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3835379/675100) [from this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3834608/675100)

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

typedef std::basic_string<unsigned char> ustring;

inline ustring convert(const std::string& sys_enc) {
  return ustring( sys_enc.begin(), sys_enc.end() );
}

template< std::size_t N >
inline ustring convert(const char (&array)[N]) {
  return ustring( array, array+N );
}

inline ustring convert(const char* pstr) {
  return ustring( reinterpret_cast<const ustring::value_type*>(pstr) );
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const ustring& u)
{
    for(auto c : u)
      os << c;
    return os;
}

int main()
{
    ustring u1 = convert(std::string("hello"));
    std::cout << u1 << '\n';

    // -----------------------
    char chars[] = { 67, 43, 43 };
    ustring u2 = convert(chars);
    std::cout << u2 << '\n';

    // -----------------------
    ustring u3 = convert("hello");
    std::cout << u3 << '\n';
}
```

[coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f8c8226570c34f4f)

Answer (score 1):

Simply use a:

```
std::vector<unsigned char> v;
```

Comment: My declaration of variable is string my_string;